# Firebase Simple Login Issue with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to use "password" authentication with Firebase Simple Login in Phonegap but getting this error:

```
Web Console(857): FirebaseSimpleLogin(): Due to browser security restrictions,
loading applications via `file://*` URLs will prevent popup-based authentication
providers from working properly. When testing locally, you'll need to run a
barebones webserver on your machine rather than loading your test files via
`file://*`. The easiest way to run a barebones server on your local machine is
to `cd` to the root directory of your code and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`,
which will allow you to access your content via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/*`. at
file:///android_asset/www/js/firebase-simple-login.js:74
```

How can we solve this problem? Also what about the Auth settings in Firebase admin GUI. How can we allow Phonegap based apps to access Firebase server?

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] This error message is a warning for users loading a file locally, but should actually be harmless for PhoneGap, provided that you are requiring the InAppBrowser and either `cordova.js` or `phonegap.js` in your application. I'll look into hiding this message for the PhoneGap case. Please reach out directly to support@firebase.com if you run into further problems.

Comment: Thanks for details. I will verify if this is a warning or an error.

Comment: Yes you are right. The message is a warning, not an error. Even though it's a warning, Firebase login is not working with Phonegap. FYI I have enabled InAppBrowser and added cordova.js

Comment: Can you reach out to support@firebase.com with this issue? We'd be happy to take a look and find the source of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The error message states pretty clearly that you can't use popup authentication when accessing a page via file://. So instead of entering a local file path into the browser, you need to run an http server, and use a URL like `http://localhost/`.

This isn't an issue with Firebase's security but instead a basic browser sandboxing feature.

Getting a server is pretty straightforward. If you're using python, as noted, you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. If node.js is more your ball of wax, there is a great, simple [http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server) lib for node as well. If you're on Mac, [you already have one](http://macs.about.com/od/networking/qt/websharing.htm), and otherwise, you could try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: You didn't got my point. I understand this issue will get fixed when we use web server. But I am not using a browser. I am using Phonegap.