# Why is Firebase returning 404 errors in PhoneGap app when running on Android emulator?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, firebase

I am using Firebase + Firebase Simple Login in a PhoneGap app and am having issues when I run the app in an Android emulator (browser-based testing works fine).

[image]

Note: I ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19729270/396070) earlier, but I added cordova.js and no loner see the security restrictions warning.

All that is happening now is 404 error responses and I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Did you add the firebase server to your whitelist?

Comment: No, I had not even thought about that.  I went ahead and added the appropriate domains to the whitelist and all is well.

Comment: We've published a blog post which will help with setup and some of the gotchas: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to add firebase.com to your app's whitelist.

Assuming you're using PhoneGap 3.x+, follow these steps:

1. Edit `config.xml` (see [Cordova's docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) for more about where that file lives)
2. Add a rule allowing firebase and subdomains:

   ```
   <access uri="https://*.firebaseio.com" subdomains="true" />
   ```

You might also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795628/error-whitelist-rejection-in-phonegap) helpful. It has a bunch of stuff in it about whitelisting in Cordova / PhoneGap.