# Genymotion emulator: Can't connect to firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using Cordova, Ionic and Firebase. Looks like the Genymotion emulator can't connect to Firebase, although I whitelisted Firebase - it works in the iOS emulator though (even without whitelisting).

My config.xml:

```
<widget>
    <access origin="https://correctname.firebaseio.com" />
</widget>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Only things I found are [Why is Firebase returning 404 errors in PhoneGap app when running on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383281/why-is-firebase-returning-404-errors-in-phonegap-app-when-running-on-android-emu) and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html.

Comment: Does it work if you whitelist `*.firebaseio.com` and / or `firebaseio.com`? Also, you can try enabling logging with `Firebase.enableLogging(true, true)`, which is often useful for debugging connection issues.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Logging just states "Long-poll script failed to load: https://correctname.firebaseio.com". My config.xml now looks like this: `<widget><access origin="http://*.firebaseio.com" />
  <access origin="https://*.firebaseio.com" />
  <access origin="https://firebaseio.com" />
  <access origin="http://firebaseio.com" /></widget>`.

Comment: Added `subdomains="true"` like suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383281/why-is-firebase-returning-404-errors-in-phonegap-app-when-running-on-android-emu?lq=1, again without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the free version of Genymotion can't connect to the internet at all, apparently oversaw that. If I had proper error messages configured, I would have figured it out earlier.